# INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY: No package named 'aura' found (Failed)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, eclipse, force.com-ide

I am trying to work with Lightning Components in the Eclipse Force.com IDE. I add the `AuraDefinitionBundle` type in the package.xml file.

I'm able to see all the Lightning components I created in the SF developer console in the package explorer. 
Unfortunately, when I try to edit a component and save my changes, I get the following error:

> Unable to perform save on all files: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY: No
>   package named 'aura' found (Failed)

Any workaround ?

Comment: Can please share your package.xml

Answer (score 1):

The lightning force.com ide works with Eclipse 4.5 or later.
With older versions was able to fetch aura components but not save them.

Install the latest eclipse. (It worked for me for neon eclipse).
Add the force.com ide from here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/media/force-ide/eclipse45.

Here are the steps in detail :
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you not included any installed packages (Like SLDS) in your package.xml.
If you included then try to remove and try deploy.